# Why is this Excel Macro Getting Run-time error 4198?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I'm running a macro that populates a word template bookmarks with various fields from excel. The macro itself runs fine and generates the letters, but every time I also get the Run-time error 4198 pop up due to the following line:

`wdDoc.SaveAs2 xlBook.Path & "\Letters\" & xlSheet.Cells(r, 1) & ".docx"`

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with the VBA so any help will be very appreciated.

Thanks,

```vb
Sub LetterGenerator()

    Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim wdApp As word.Application
    Dim wdDoc As word.Document
    Dim wdTemplatePath As String

    Dim r As Long

    '// INSTANIATE EXCEL OBJECTS
    Set xlBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set xlSheet = xlBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    '// INSTANIATE WORD OBJECTS
    Set wdApp = New word.Application

    '// SET TEMPLATE PATH
    wdTemplatePath = xlBook.Path & "\Letters\letterDoc.docx"

    '// LOOP THORUGH EXCEL DATA ROWS
    For r = 2 To xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    '// OPEN TEMPLATE
    Set wdDoc = wdApp.Documents.Open(wdTemplatePath, , True)

    '// LOOP THROUGH EXCEL COLUMNS
    For c = 2 To xlSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count
        '// FILL BOOKMARK
        wdDoc.Bookmarks(xlSheet.Cells(1, c)).Range = xlSheet.Cells(r, c)
    Next c
    
      '// SAVE AS DOC
    wdDoc.SaveAs2 xlBook.Path & "\Letters\" & xlSheet.Cells(r, 1) & ".docx"

     '// SAVE AS PDF
    wdDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat xlBook.Path & "\Letters\" & xlSheet.Cells(r, 1) & ".pdf", wdExportFormatPDF


    '// CLOSE WORD TEMPLATE
    wdDoc.Close False
    
    '// RELEASE OBJECT
    Set wdDoc = Nothing
    Next r

    '// QUIT WORD
    wdApp.Quit

    '// RELEASE OBJECTS
    Set wdApp = Nothing
    Set xlSheet = Nothing
    Set xlBook = Nothing

End Sub
```

Someone recommended adding the following but it didn't work:

```vb
Sub UpdateBookmark(doc As Word.Document, bookmarkName As String, replacementText As String)
    On Error Resume Next
    doc.Bookmarks(bookmarkName).Range.Text = replacementText
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: `xlBook` is `ThisWorkbook`..... have you saved the file yet?  If not, ThisWorkbook has no path.  Any illegal filename characters in `xlSheet.Cells(r, 1)`?  If you put `?xlBook.Path & "\Letters\" & xlSheet.Cells(r, 1) & ".docx"` in the Immediate window does it return a valid path?

Comment: Hi. Yes, the workbooks is saved down and the filename avoids any illegal characters except spaces, though removing these still returns the same runtime error.

Putting ?xlBook.Path & "\Letters\" & xlSheet.Cells(r, 1) & ".docx" returns Run-time error 424 in the Immediate window but I'm unsure why as the macro saves to the path fine.

Comment: Are there any blank cells in the used range. Add `Msgbox xlSheet.UsedRange.Address` after `Set xlSheet = ..`

Comment: Does the `Letters` folder already exist?  If you make `wdApp` Visible that may give you some other info you're not seeing with it being hidden.

Comment: Thanks. So `MsgBox xlSheet.UsedRange.Address` returns `$A$1:$J$19`, but depending on letter volumes, not all cells will be populated.

Comment: When I make `wdApp` visible, it almost looks like the word docs are protected but there's no restrictions or protections on the file.

Comment: Are all the cells in column A - A$2:$A$19 populated ?

Comment: No, it's only A2:A10 that are populated for this one.

Comment: "it almost looks like the word docs are protected" - how exactly does it look?  Are you using a local/network drive, or are your files on OneDrive/SharePoint?

Comment: I'm just saving them to a desktop folder, and Word opens with no page and the **PROTECTED VIEW Be careful - files from the internet can contain viruses....Enable Editing** bar at the top.

Comment: Instead of `xlSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count` try `xlSheet.Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row`.

Comment: Bingo @CDP1802! That worked perfectly, and the run-time error has stopped. Thanks so much for sorting this out.